# The operand of the column function "MAX" includes a column function, a scalar fullselect, or a subquery.

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, pivot

I am trying to get number of people by age and county. Below is a picture what I am trying to achieve. Just like a Pivot table[image]

```
SELECT 
country,
MAX (CASE WHEN Age = '0' THEN  count(age) END) AS total0,
MAX (CASE WHEN Age = '1' THEN  count(age) END) AS total1,
MAX (CASE WHEN Age = '2' THEN  count(age) END) AS total2,
MAX (CASE WHEN Age = '3' THEN  count(age) END) AS total3,
MAX (CASE WHEN Age = '4' THEN  count(age) END) AS total4,
MAX (CASE WHEN Age = '5' THEN  count(age) END) AS total5
FROM (

SELECT person_id,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(256,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(a.admission_date) - TIMESTAMP(p.dateofbirth))) AS Age, 
dateofbirth,
a.admission_date

FROM person p
LEFT JOIN admission a ON p.person_id = a.person_id
WHERE category = '1' AND startdate BETWEEN '8/1/2016' AND '10/31/2017') AS a 

WHERE age <= '5'

GROUP BY country
```

This codes give me this error: The operand of the column function "MAX" includes a column function, a scalar fullselect, or a subquery. Please help thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are trying to aggregate your aggregate.....

```
MAX(COUNT(*))
```

But the reality is you really only want to `COUNT()` and don't need the `MAX()` at all.

```
SELECT 
country,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = '0' THEN  person_id END) AS total0,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = '1' THEN  person_id END) AS total1,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = '2' THEN  person_id END) AS total2,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = '3' THEN  person_id END) AS total3,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = '4' THEN  person_id END) AS total4,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Age = '5' THEN  person_id END) AS total5
FROM (

SELECT person_id,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(256,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(a.admission_date) - TIMESTAMP(p.dateofbirth))) AS Age, 
dateofbirth,
a.admission_date

FROM person p
LEFT JOIN admission a ON p.person_id = a.person_id
WHERE category = '1' AND startdate BETWEEN '8/1/2016' AND '10/31/2017') AS a 

WHERE age <= '5'

GROUP BY country
```